# Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, html, offset

In my current PHP script this error comes up: Undefined offset: 1

My code is here:

```
$query = "SELECT item_id, username, item_content FROM updates ORDER BY update_time DESC                 LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $number_of_posts;

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            preg_match("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/",$row['item_content'],$matches);
            $row['item_content'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
            $posts[] = $row;
        }
```

If you see whats causing this, posting below would really help. Thanks! :)

Comment: and also accept some answers than people would want to help u more ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
$row['item_content'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
```

Try

```
if (isset($matches[0]) && isset($matches[0][1]))
  $row['item_content'] = strip_tags($matches[0][1]);
else
  $row['item_content'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is on this line:

```
$row['item_content'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Agreed, I think it's an improper use of strip_tags -- strip_tags should be used on a whole string -- if $matches is a string (which, judging by the preg_match line it should be), then $matches[1] would just be a single character, right?

Answer (score 0):

As Neal said, there is a problem on that line. It seems that $matches[1] is undefined (i.e. there are no mathces, or there is only 1 match, $matches[0]). Make sure your table is working correctly.