# How to access sub array in JSON - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have posted parts of this.. but this a different question for it

i have the below

```
foreach ($results['comments'] as $item) {

  echo 'Date: '. $item['created_at'] .'<br/>';
  echo 'Description : '. $item['html_body'] .'<br/>';
  echo 'Attachments : '. $item['attacments->url'] .'<br/>';
  echo 'Filename : '. $item['file_name'] .'<br/>';
  echo "<br>";
}
```

So basically, my Date and Description work, BUT the attachments wont work, b/c i dont think thats the correct way to get an object thats within an array of an array? hope i explained it correctly.

the comments array has all the date as a single object and so is description, then it has this trailing.

```
[public] => 1 [trusted] => 1 [attachments] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://url/api/v2/attachments/IDHERE.json [id] => ID#[file_name] => name of file here
```

Comment: try `$item['attachments'][0]['url']`

Comment: How about file_name? would it be $item['attachments'][0]['url'][0]['id'][0]['file_name'] @Nouphal.M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your array dump

```
[public] => 1
[trusted] => 1
[attachments] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [url] => https://url/api/v2/attachments/IDHERE.json
        [id] => ID#
        [file_name] => name of file here
```

Get the values like this:

```
$Attachments = $item['attachments'];
$AttachmentsUrl = $Attachments[0]['url'];
$Attachmentsid = $Attachments[0]['id'];
$AttachmentsFileName = $Attachments[0]['file_name'];
```

Comment: can i ask, since the code is giving me an error of PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  0, can't i use the name of the array instead? how would that look @meda

Comment: @user3100345 if it throws an error, it means `$Attachments[0]` does not have any element at that index

Comment: Should i put an if statement?

Comment: @user3100345 yes check if attachment array is set, maybe not all you comments have attachment, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880670/1880431) coincidentally it simillar to your case